# make -e only exit from subshell

Tags: bash, shell, subshell

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

items="1 2"
for item in $items; do
(
    echo one
    false
    echo two
) ||:
done
```

I wish `false` line to break a subshell, but continue processing the outer loop. I.e. the expected output is

```
one
one
```

however, I get

```
one
two
one
two
```

as if `||:` stands exactly after `false` line, not after the subshell.

Can anyone explain, why does this happen?

Comment: As I understand the COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT section of the `bash` man page, only subshells spawned by command substitutions (`$(...)`) inherit the `-e` option.

Comment: I don't think so, if remove `||:` at the end, the script fails successfully on `false` line.

Comment: Good point. However, here's another question: when the subshell does exit, presumably it exits with non-zero status due to the false, in which case: why does the shell executing the `for`-loop not exit as well? In other words, why does "one" print twice?

Comment: Didn't get you. "one" printed twice is what I'm trying to achieve, if you remove `||:` at the end, the script will fail both in subshell and in outer shell, printing "one" once.

Comment: I would think that with `set -e`, the entire script would exit if the subshell exited, so you would see `one` printed *once*, the script would exit, and the loop would never execute the second time.

Comment: With `set -e` at the very beginning of a script, yes, it only prints `one` once and exits immediately... Is that what you were asking about? >_<

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30094/discussion-between-chepner-and-ixanezis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `-e` inside the subshell and remove the `||:`:

```
#!/bin/bash -u

items="1 2"
for item in $items; do
(
    set -e
    echo one
    false
    echo two
)
done
```

Another seemingly working approach is:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

items="1 2"
for item in $items; do
(
    echo one
    false
    echo two
) | awk '{print}'
done
```

I suppose the reason why your approach doesn't work is the following (quoted from `man bash`):

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is [...] part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`

Comment: Because of the `-e`, I suppose.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, thanks for informing, then there's no need for same thing to be repeated :) I removed my answer

Comment: So why doesn't it work in my implementation? Looks like a hack to add a `set +e` right before the loop, `set -e` in a subshell and another `set -e` after the loop.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers To me, that would seem to apply only to a command that is *directly* part of the `&&` or `||` list. However, given that the behavior is identical in versions 3.x and 4.x, and your quote from the version 4 man page is more explicit and closer to the observed behavior than the text in the version 3 man page, I think this is correct.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Looks like you're right. I knew that section of bash you're quoting.. Just couldn't realize that `false` line from inside the subshell is actually a part of long command, followed by `||`. Thanks for  your answer, though I'm still looking for a nicer solution, cause your second one 1) also fails with `set -o pipefail` turned on and 2) from the first glance someone would ask "What is this awk '{print}' doing here..?"

Comment: I have to admit that this looks like the best solution of all. It is discussed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/why-does-set-e-not-work-inside) and [here](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=52). The only thing I'd change is replacing `awk '{print}'` with `cat`.